# remove parent key in hash if no value in child present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

i have hash that looks like

```
parent:{
  child:{}
}
```

How do i delete `parent` key if `child` is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Hash#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) method.

```
hash.delete_if { |k,v| k == :parent && v[:child].empty? }
```